# Kahler structure on holomorphic principal bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $G$ be a compact complex Lie group and $M$ be a compact Kähler manifold.
Does there exist any example of a holomorphic principal $G$-bundle over $M$ admitting Kähler structures?

Comment: Are there many compact complex Lie groups? Aren't they all tori? If $G$ is K\"ahler itself, what about the trivial bundle $M\times G\to M$: it is holomorphic and admits a K\"ahler metric.

Comment: As Alex says, a compact complex Lie group is a complex torus. A result of Atyiah says that if the total space of a torus bundle over a simply connected Kahler manifold is Kahler, then the bundle is trivial. Looking at such bundles is actually one of the main methods of constructing non-Kahler manifolds.

Comment: A compact complex Lie group is an extension of a finite group by a complex torus.

Comment: What's a "principle" bundle?

Comment: compact coadjoint orbits?

Answer (score 1):

A connected compact complex Lie group is a torus, hence the question is apparently about principal torus bundles. Of course, product of a torus and a compact Kahler manifold is Kahler, giving a trivial answer to your question. For non-trivial examples, one may take a finite quotient of a trivial torus fibration by a finite group acting freely and compatible with the fibration structure.